# How draw caption in alt+tab switcher when paint custom caption(frame)?

Tags: windows, gdi, paint

I need to draw a custom caption bar, where I draw the window caption by myself.

```
    HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
    if (hdc && prepareTitleBarDC(getWidth(), 27)) {
        SetWindowText(hwnd, _T(""));
        DefWindowProc(hwnd, WM_NCPAINT, wParam, lParam);
        m_titleBar->setSize(getWidth(), 27);
        m_titleBar->setBkColor(SkColorSetARGB(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00));
        m_titleBar->paintEvent(m_pTitleBarDC);
        FnSkBitmap::SaveSkBitmap(m_pTitleBarDC->canvas(), L"e:\\titlebar.bmp");

        HDC hdcPaint = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, getWidth(), 27);
        SelectObject(hdcPaint, hbm);
        FnSkBitmap::DrawSkBitmap(m_pTitleBarDC->bitmap(), hdcPaint);
        BLENDFUNCTION bfn = {0};
        bfn.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
        bfn.BlendFlags = 0;
        bfn.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
        bfn.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
        AlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, getWidth(), 27, hdcPaint, 0, 0, getWidth(), 27, bfn);
    }
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    return 0;
```

And use AlphaBlend to mix the standard frame with myself, but if I use SetWindowText(_T("")), then the title in Alt+Tab switcher gone.

I try to handle WM_GETTEXT message and return the caption string, but failed. How could I draw the caption text by myself but still make the title in alt+tab switcher?

Comment: Use `SetWindowText` to set the text that the Alt+Tab window sees. But when you draw your custom caption bar, don't bother drawing the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already drawing a "custom caption bar" there is no reason to have it actually draw using the actual window's text

there are two ways to accomplish this, one using the traditional `DrawCaption` from Win9x Win32Api, the other is using the more fresher "theme api"

here is an example that uses both:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Uxtheme.h>
#include <vssym32.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

const LPCWSTR WINDOW_CLASS = L"Test Window Class";
const LPCWSTR WINDOW_CAPTION = L"This is my test window";
const LPCWSTR CUSTOM_CAPTION = L"Custom Caption Text";

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wndClassEx = {};

    wndClassEx.lpszClassName = WINDOW_CLASS;
    wndClassEx.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClassEx.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wndClassEx.cbSize = sizeof(wndClassEx);
    wndClassEx.hCursor = (HCURSOR) LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW), IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_SHARED | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
    wndClassEx.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_DROPSHADOW;

    ATOM registeredClass = RegisterClassEx(&wndClassEx);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        WINDOW_CLASS,
        WINDOW_CAPTION,
        WS_SYSMENU,

        200, 200, 500, 300,

        NULL, // parent
        NULL, // menu
        hInstance,
        NULL // extra
        );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            // fill the window with a color
            HBRUSH hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(33, 33, 33));
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, hbrush);
            DeleteObject(hbrush);

            // get a drawing area
            RECT rect = {};
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            rect.bottom = rect.top + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE) * 2;

            // draw a simple win9x style caption (switch out the window text while drawing)
            SetWindowText(hwnd, CUSTOM_CAPTION);
            DrawCaption(hwnd, hdc, &rect, DC_GRADIENT | DC_TEXT | DC_ACTIVE | DC_ICON);
            SetWindowText(hwnd, WINDOW_CAPTION);

            // use theme framework
            HTHEME htheme = OpenThemeData(hwnd, L"Window");

            // move downwards and then use new APIs for size
            rect.top += rect.bottom + 20;
            rect.bottom = rect.top + GetThemeSysSize(htheme, SM_CYSIZE) + GetThemeSysSize(htheme, SM_CXPADDEDBORDER) * 2;

            // draw the background
            DrawThemeBackground(htheme, hdc, WP_CAPTION, CS_ACTIVE, &rect, &ps.rcPaint);

            // load the caption font and save the old one
            LOGFONTW captionfont = {};
            GetThemeSysFont(htheme, TMT_CAPTIONFONT, &captionfont);
            HFONT newfont = CreateFontIndirect(&captionfont);
            HGDIOBJ oldfont = SelectObject(hdc, newfont);

            // center the font and draw
            rect.top += GetThemeSysSize(htheme, SM_CXPADDEDBORDER);
            DrawThemeTextEx(htheme, hdc, WP_CAPTION, CS_ACTIVE, CUSTOM_CAPTION, -1, DT_CENTER, &rect, NULL);

            // cleanup fonts
            SelectObject(hdc, oldfont);
            DeleteObject(newfont);

            // adjust draw location, load icon and draw
            rect.left += GetThemeSysSize(htheme, SM_CXPADDEDBORDER) * 2;
            rect.top += GetThemeSysSize(htheme, SM_CXPADDEDBORDER);
            HICON icon = (HICON) LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_SHARED | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
            DrawIconEx(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, icon, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);


            // close theme
            CloseThemeData(htheme);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        }
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

the resulting window looks like:

[image: screenshot of resulting window]

You can see that the 2 "custom drawn" title bars display custom text, not the text on the window.

A quick glance at the code will tell you that attempting the theme window caption using a custom routine is a lot more difficult than the legacy.  The trade off of course is that it gives you way more control.  You'll also take note that I switch out the window text to make it display what I want when using the legacy method.  Additionally you need to remember that the legacy method takes its queues on how to draw itself from the styles associated with the window, if your window style has no icon, it will not draw one even if you specify it...

Either of these techniques will accomplish your goal. If I switched this code around not to draw multiple title bars and get rid of the default one created by the window style the result would look like:

[image: screenshot showing result]
you can see here how the task switch still displays the actual window text, and my "custom" caption bar looks like the real deal...

good luck, i hope this helps -ck

on a side note: i am running Windows8 and am not sure why the caption drawing routines are ignoring my theme... perhaps i forgot a directive